# how to get data NO ID with join table in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

my data there will be a number key how to equalize with another table so it can be called names. i want to changes data (number key) to text from other table.

my table1 :

```
+-----------------------+
| ID  | Name | Category |
-------------------------
|  1  | Home |    21    |
|  2  | Pro  |    23    |
+-----------------------+
```

and table 2 :

```
+---------------------+
| ID  | name_category |
-----------------------
|  21 |   Sweet Home  |
|  23 |   your Home   |
+---------------------+
```

how to get the same ID?. but the data will be shown in table 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.Use `join` on `table1.ID = table2.ID`.displays all data of `table1` with category names from `table2` matching on table1 `category ID`.

```
$this->db->select(*)
         ->from('table1')
         ->join('table2', 'table1.ID = table2.ID');
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
print_r($result);//displays all data of table1 with category names from table2 matching on table1 category ID.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->query('select table1.* from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id');
$this->db->result();
```